# Display inactive thumbnail as grey in CSS and Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

When I click on a thumbnail, I'd like it to display in color and the other thumbnails as grey. 
So When you click on a thumbnail is active and to illustrate I want to have the thumbnail in color, and the other thumbnails in grey because they are inactive.

This is what I'd like to achieve:
[image: project picture]

```js
Vue.component('carousel', {
    template: `
        <div class="card-carousel" >
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <div 
                    v-for="(image, index) in  images"
                    :key="image.id"
                    :class="['thumbnail-image', (activeImage == index) ? 'active' : '']"
                    @click="activateImage(index)">
                    <img :src="image.thumb"/>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="containe-carousel">

                <span> {{currentImage.text}}</span>
            <div class="photoshop-screenshot">                
            <img :src="currentImage.big"  alt="">
                    
            </div>
            <div class="card-img">
                <img :src="currentImage2.big2" alt="">
                   

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    computed: {

        currentImage() {
            return this.images[this.activeImage];
        },

        currentImage2() {
            return this.images[this.activeImage];
        }
     
    },

        data() {
            return {
                activeImage: 0,
            
            }
        },

        methods: {     
            activateImage(imageIndex) {
                this.activeImage = imageIndex;
            },  
            
        
        },
    
        props: ['images']
    });
```

```css
.section{
    background-color: black;
}

.card-carousel {
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
}

.containe-carousel {
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.thumbnails {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: row;

}

.thumbnail-image {
    display: fixed;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px;

}

.thumbnail-image > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: all 250ms;
    filter:  grayscale(100%);

}

.thumbnail-image:selected> img {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    visibility: hidden;
    filter: none;
}


.card-img {
    position: relative;
}

 .card-img > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 7%;
    z-index: 2; 
}

 .photoshop-screenshot {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 70%;
    right:-80px;
    bottom:-130px;
   
}


.containe-carousel span {
    
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: -0.3125em 0.3125em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
                 
        <section class="section" id="app">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center" style="margin:0px 50px">
                    <div class="heading-underscore">
                        <h2 class="dk-5q-color">
                             <?php say("X50Q-dashboard-title"); ?>
                         </h2> 
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="columns">
                     <div class="column "> 
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <carousel
                                :starting-image="0"
                                :show-progress-bar="true"
                                :images="images"     
                            ></carousel>
                    
                        </div>   
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>            
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
    
<script src ="/x/x50q-rgb-mechanical-keyboard/x50q-cloud-js.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() { 
                
                return {
                    images: [
                       
                        {
                            text : 'Photoshop',
                            id: '1',
                            big: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/photoshop-profile.PNG',
                            big2: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/photoshop-screenshot.png',
                            thumb: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/photoshop-logo.jpg'
                        },
                        {
                            text : 'Aurocad',
                            id: '2',
                            big: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/autocad-profile.png',
                            big2: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/autocad-screenshot.png',
                            thumb: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/autocad-logo.png'
                        },
                        {
                            text : ' Counter-Strike',
                            id: '3',
                            big: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/counterstrike-profile.png',
                            big2: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/counterstrike-screenshot.jpg',
                            thumb: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/counterstrike-logo.png'
                        },
                        {
                            text : 'League of Legends',
                            id: '4',
                            big: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/leagueoflegends-profile.png',
                            big2: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/leagueoflegends-screenshot.png',
                            thumb: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/leagueoflegends-logo.jpg'
                        }
                    ],
                    
                
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: can i use jquery ?

Comment: if yes i will make look exactly the same on the provided picture

Comment: In my code I don't use jquery sorry

Comment: Are you able to post your HTML as well? We need enough of your [mcve] code that we can reproduce your problem in order to show a solution.

Comment: Ok I’ll post once I reach home

Comment: The CSS entirely suffices to infer the rest and find a solution.

Comment: @Ahmed Shahin: IMO using JavaScript / JQuery here would be like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer.

Comment: but it's giving you more ability in style though , i will start now just arrived home

Comment: what's wrong with my page ?? i have did exactly what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

I'd rotate the filter from `.thumbnails` to `.thumbnail-image>img` instead and add a `filter: none;` to `.thumbnail-image:active>img`

Your CSS should look like this:

```
.thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: row;
  }

.thumbnail-image {
  display: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px;
  }

.thumbnail-image>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 250ms;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  }

.thumbnail-image:active>img {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  visibility: hidden;
  filter: none;
  }
```

The problem is that when you add the grayscale filter to the container of class `thumbnails`, you are essentially overwriting anything that may have been set inside. If you want to affect the thumbnail images, you should make it as specific as possible, that's why `.thumbnail-image>img` is your primary target. Furthermore, when you click on the thumbnail you need to undo this change so `.thumbnail-image:active>img` is your override.

Comment: but with your code, the color appear only when I click on the icon, and I wish the color stay when I click on the icon and It is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the wished result add this attribute `class="active"` to the `img` tag as follow:

```
<img :src="image.thumb" class="active"/>
```

and add the following rule to your CSS :

```
.active{ 
   filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(19deg) saturate(98) brightness(98%) ; 
   border:3px solid #fff; 
 }
```

this gives a light green color but you could change the filter functions to achieve the desired colour.